# Create a line chart by separating a variable into two with each being a separate line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Say I have a data frame with the columns for Date (DATE), Status of the employee (Status), and the number of employees with that status (n), how do I then go about creating a line chart to diplay the change in time of the number of each employee status with each status being an individual line.

```
df %>%
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(DATE, n, colour = Status)
```

When using this it returns a grpah with exponential values on the y-axis:

Does any-one have any solutions? With there only being two differetn status values, I tried using pivot_wider() to make each a separate varivble, however I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data something like this

```
df <- data.frame(Date = rep(as.Date(seq(18628, 18677), origin= "1970-01-01"), 2),
                  Status = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50),
                  emp_nos = rpois(100, 100))

# A tibble: 100 x 3
   Date       Status emp_nos
   <date>     <chr>    <int>
 1 2021-01-01 A           83
 2 2021-01-02 A           99
 3 2021-01-03 A          104
 4 2021-01-04 A          111
 5 2021-01-05 A          102
 6 2021-01-06 A           91
 7 2021-01-07 A           96
 8 2021-01-08 A          102
 9 2021-01-09 A           97
10 2021-01-10 A           98
# ... with 90 more rows
```

you may create a chart like this

```
df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y = emp_nos, linetype = Status, color = Status), size =1)
```

[image]